# Print_r returns value of Array()

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Now, I am loosing my patience haha :D

Problem is that, that whatever I tried, I couldn't fix problem.

In my php code, I successfully connected to database, sent $_POST variable through ajax to it,

and after all, in $result I stored:

```
$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

But after when I call print_r:

```
print_r($result);
```

Always but always I get "Array()".

After 1000 changes, all possibilities tried, nothing was able to fetch data from table.

What possibly gone wrong?

Code looks like:

```
<?php

$mov = (isset($_POST['movie'])) ? $_POST['movie'] : null;

if ($mov != null)
{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=workstation', 'root', 'password');

    $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name LIKE '%:mov%'");
    $q->bindValue(':mov', $mov, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();
    $r = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $c = $q->rowCount();

    print_r($r);
    echo $c;

    /*
     * $name = $r[$key]->name; // in foreach loop for all found...
     * there should be returned
     * $res .= '<div>'.$name.'</div>'
     */
}
else
{
    $result = 'Type query...';
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Could you show us the sql-query itself?

Comment: Maybe it is an empty resultset of a query?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention in question that echo $c = $query->rowsCount() returns value of 1, so it is not empty, and query executed is:

"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name LIKE '$mov'"

Comment: @Floris: On an *empty* array?!

Comment: What happens if you leave off the `WHERE` part of the query? Oh - and I really hope you are testing your code with a less powerful user than `toot`...

Comment: how it can be used without WHERE what is the point when i must specify column name and for root... no... i use my whole system in root mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT nom, couleur FROM fruit");
$q->execute();

$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

may be you didnt execute your prepared statement thats why it gives you blank array. try it may be works... put your query in place of my query..